Spring Batch Tasklet Fails with "Thread Interrupted" After Migration to Spring Boot
I have a Spring Batch job that runs a Tasklet every minute using a scheduled trigger. The Tasklet processes data successfully, but intermittently throws the following error:
[ERROR] [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep:doInTransaction():430] - 
Thread interrupted while locking for repository update

When this error occurs:
The batch tables (BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION) show the job status as STOPPED.
The Tasklet is already finished its work when this error appears.
Key Points:
This issue started after migrating my Spring Batch job to Spring Boot.
Prior to migration, the Tasklet ran without issues.
I suspect this might be related to thread interruption or Spring’s job repository behavior.
Questions

What could be causing this "Thread interrupted while locking for repository update" error?
How can I ensure that Tasklet execution completes cleanly without thread interruptions?
Are there configuration changes needed in Spring Boot to handle this issue, given that it appeared after the migration?

